# Automatically create new objects in a Plone Folder, being the ids only sequential numbers

Tags: plone

I have the following structure:

```
/Plone/folder/year/month/day/id
```

I want to create the last `id` sequentially in a tool using invokeFactory. I want to have:

```
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/1
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/2
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/3
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/4
```

Instead of:

```
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/id-1
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/id-2
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/id-3
/Plone/folder/2011/06/21/id-4
```

...that is automatically done when I try to create an object with the same name in a folder, Plone handles that for me adding a sequential number. I want an efficient way to create objects, but only using a sequential number instead of a name with a sequential number. I can do that getting the total number os items in a folder, but would like to know if there's a better way.

Real life example: http://plone.org/products/collective.captcha/issues/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating these objects manually, you can do something like:

```
brains = context.getFolderContents({'sort_on' : 'id', 'sort_order' : "reverse"})
if len(brains) > 0:
  id = str(int(brains[0].id) + 1)
else:
  id = '1'
```

Then you'll have to create the object manually with that id.

If you want this to do done automatically for you when a user creates content, you might want to look into creating a content rule to change the id of the content for you. An example that might help is [collective.contentrules.yearmonth](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.contentrules.yearmonth/trunk)

Comment: This solution can be a problem when you delete objects, because you'll get the same id twice. I use a similar approach of: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gocept.sequence/